# State Machine with If/Else?

Tags: arduino-mega, programming

I am trying to make a state machine with if/else. But some of the code does not seem to be executing. I have information being displayed on an LCD screen so I know where it is, and it stays on **Todo=1** and does not go to the next state. I have tried using switch/case and it works. But I think it might be better for my project if I use if/else. Can I do this using if/else?

```
Void loop{
  if (state == PLAY) {
    Todo = 1;
    Mastermachine(Todo);
  } else if (state == TRYAGIN) {

  }
}

void Mastermachine(int Todo) {
  if (Todo == 1) {
    lcd.setCursor(16, 2);
    lcd.print(String(Todo));
    SongSeq[largestindex];
    for (int index = 0; index < largestindex; index++) {
      SongSeq[index]();
    }
    Todo = 2;
  } else if (Todo == 2) {
    for (learnindex = 0; learnindex < largestindex;) {
      MIDI.read();
      if (learnindex >= largestindex) {
        Todo = 3;
      }
      lcd.setCursor(16, 2);
      lcd.print(String(Todo));
    }
  } else  if (Todo == 3) {
    if (array_cmp(learn, note, largestindex, largestindex) == true) {
      largestindex++;
      delay(2000);
      Todo = 1;
    } else {
      delay(2000);
      Todo = 1;
    }
    lcd.setCursor(16, 2);
    lcd.print(String(Todo));
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider a switch statement instead of the if/else statements.

Comment: Make the state a global variable. `Todo` is lost after each call of `MasterMachine()` (if you do no introduce a loop).

Answer (score 1):

Inside Mastermachine(), Todo is *a copy* whatever is passed as its paramter. Even if you make a global named Todo, it will be 'hidden' by the parameter of the same name. That parameter goes out of scope - disappears - when Mastermachine() exits, including any changes made to it within the function.

There are a few choices to accomplish what you want to do, but the easiest is probably to make a global Todo and get rid of the parameter Todo in Mastermachine(); i.e., make it `void Mastermachine(void)`. Then the name Todo inside the function will refer to the global by that name.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop executes continually, always setting the state to 1.....

The called state machine supposedly changes the state, but it get set back to 1 every time the loop executes.

The loop program needs to do the state changes, not the masternachine function.

Comment: would moving Todo=1 somewhere else fix that issue ?

Comment: If you want to have Todo=1 set only once, place it in setup.